# set image inside circle shaped layout and hide overlapping part

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm using frame layout and I've added imageview into it. frame layout is circled shape. the imageview inside frame layout moves outside of that circle when it's size gets bigger than layout size. I want to hide that extra imageview. any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function...

You need to provide your square bitmap file and output size of the circle image you want.

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int size) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, size, size, false);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
           bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    int color = 0xff424242;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I don't want circle image, i want circle shaped layout which will have imageview inside and I'll be able to move that imageview onTouch movement.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use canvas for this purpose.

Draw a circular canvas and add you image bitmap in it.

For your refs https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

You can use this lib in your project

just add this in xml

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />
```

Comment: I don't want circular image, i want circle shaped layout which will have imageview inside and I'll be able to move that imageview onTouch movement.